Checking continuity of $\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ at the origin employing polar coordinates
I've seen many MSE posts where people state that
$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$$
isn't continuous at the origin and it can clearly be seen taking the limit as $\boldsymbol x\to \mathbf 0$ in the direction $x=my^2$. Namely,
$$\lim_{\boldsymbol x\to \mathbf 0}\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}\overset{x=my^2}{=}\lim_{\boldsymbol x\to \mathbf 0}\dfrac{my^4}{m^2y^4+y^4}=\dfrac{m}{1+m^2}$$
and since the limit depends on the direction, it does not exist and therefore $f$ isn't continuous at the origin.
The thing is I've never seen anyone argue its discontinuity employing polar coordinates (that's what I did in the first place). So the limit would become
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}$$
but I can't see how any $\theta$ can make that limit different from $0$ and thus make the function discontinuous. Any ideas?

Note that continuous means the limit is the same when approaching the origin from any path, not just straight lines.

Oh, I see. For some reason I thought polar coordinates accounted for any path. Thanks for clarifying.

The equivalent of $x=my^2$ is $\sin(\theta)=mr\cos^2(\theta)$
So, approaching $(0,0)$ along $r=\frac {\sin(\theta)}{m\cos^2(\theta)}$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{m\cos(\theta)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta) + \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{ m^2 \cos^2(\theta) }}$$
Which simplifies to
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{m\cos(\theta)}{1 + m^2 \cos^2(\theta)}=\frac{m}{1 + m^2 }$$
